# Size of the independent set in a symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

- Let $G$ be a group and  any subset $T$ of $G$ is said to be an independent set in $G$ if $a \notin <T\backslash \{a\}> \; \forall a \in T$

> Let $S_n$ be a symmetric group of degree $n.$ Then the size of the independent set is atmost $n-1$.

I know that the transpositions set $\{ (1 2) , (2 3), \cdots ,(n-1 n)\}$  is independent, but how to prove that size of  any independent set  is atmost $n-1$.
 Any help would be appreciated. Thank you